# Is it possible to debug the WF used to build in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build-process, workflow-foundation

Guess the title asks the Q really. I want to see what's going on on a step-by-step basis for the build process that I've inherited.

I've only just started to play with WF and whilst I understand it is possible to debug a workflow I've really no idea how to go about it in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug everything, starting from custom WorkflowServiceHost (if you have one), particular code-based activities, xaml based activities, up to activity designer surface.

I believe the biggest question for you is how to debug a visual components? On the designer surface, you can place a breakpoint on activity you want to debug, and once the activity is reached, process will halt and wait for you to continue. Then just proceed as usual, nothing much different than regular debugging.

Comment: I did not know that. Sadly(not really sad at all) I'm going to be away from my desk for 3 weeks, but I will defo try this out when I get back.

Comment: One of the great features of Workflow Foundation is ability to set tracking participants. You can use those in situations where you don't want to actually debug the process but would like to be aware of specific transitions of workflow instance, such as going Idle, or being Abandoned, etc.